# Trying to create a variable out of a column argument

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a variable for a value in SQL.

I am getting the error "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"

here is the SQl I am trying to run

```
DECLARE title VARCHAR2(1) := 'N';
BEGIN
SELECT Title_Flag into title
FROM Control.Title WHERE Title_Flag=title;  
END;
```

Comment: If you run just the select, it should return only one item to assign to the title variable. If the select returns more than one result, SQL will be unable to assign the variable with multiple results.

Comment: if I run the SELECT and hardcode the value of Title_flag as 'N' it works just fine. Its when i try to create a variable with the value is where I am having the issue.

Comment: What type and version of SQL is this?

Comment: Sorry just made an edit there to add the into.

When i run the Select Statement without the Into I get 134 rows

Comment: To assign a variable, you must have a `SELECT` that runs exactly one result, otherwise SQL doesn't know which of your 134 rows to assign to the variable `title`. Your `SELECT` needs to be modified until it returns a single row.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE title VARCHAR2(1) := 'N';
BEGIN
SELECT Title_Flag into title
FROM Control.Title WHERE Title_Flag=title and rownum = 1;  
END;
```

You need to use some sort of condition to get only 1 row returned from your query as the error means you are getting more than 1 record so it doesn't know which to assign